# Bruteforce BIP39 seed phrase?

Tags: mnemonic, bip39

I have a couple words unclear/missing from my 24-word BIP39 seed phrase, which unlocks my Ethereum address.

I want to bruteforce through all possible seed phrases and find the one. It shouldn't take more than ~10 million attempts in my estimation.

Could you please outline the optimal algorithm for me? So far I've came up with something like this:

1. Set up `geth` node;
2. Install a wallet software, which allows import of custom seed phrases (like `Ethers.js`);
3. Create my own piece of software, which browses through the list of possible seed phrases, generates ETH addresses and checks if there's a match.
4. Run the software and wait for the result.

Is that it? Am I missing something?